# Pluralization is not working on form's validation message in Symfony 2.3

Tags: validation, symfony, translation, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am using Symfony 2.3.

I have created simple order form using `$this->createFormBuilder` in my controller. I am validating one Doctrine field with:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Length(min=3)
 */
protected $name;
```

However, upon validation fail, I get a *duplicated* error message near the field:

> This value is too short. It should have 3 character or more.|This value is too short. It should have 3 characters or more.

My template for this element is as simple as:

```
{{ form_errors(form.name) }}
{{ form_label(form.name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

Everything else seems to bet working as expected, except for that validation error message being duplicated. As if pluralization would not be working. Anyone has a suggestion on why this would be failing?

**EDIT**

It seems that SonataAdminBundle is overriding `form_errors` block. How to remove that override from non-sonata controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had set this in my `config.yml`:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

    form:
        resources:
            - 'SonataAdminBundle:Form:silex_form_div_layout.html.twig'
            - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

The `silex_form_div_layout.html.twig` one overrides `form_errors` Twig block, and removing it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the sonata's template is not in sync with the latest changes from the original template.

Can you create a PR or an issue on github, thanks